# Using file_get_contents and use specific parts of the content from table havinfg class

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm fetching data from another website using `file_get_contents()`, but I need to extract a `<table>` element with class `inputpanelfields`, e.g.:

```
...
<table class="inputpanelfields">
<!-- this is what I need -->
</table>
...
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$body = file_get_contents('http://example.org/path/to/page');
$d = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$d->loadHTML($body);
libxml_clear_errors();

$x = new DOMXPath($d);
if (($table = $x->query('//table[contains(@class, "inputpanelfields")]'))) {
    echo $d->saveHTML($table->item(0));
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2OqdJs)

Comment: i got this error bro   Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <html> tag in Entity, line: 214 in D:\xampplite\htdocs\fetchdata\getdata.php on line 5

Comment: May be your famous HTML code is not well form, check its content

Comment: @BhavnishNarang That's not an error, but just a warning. I've updated my answer to deal with badly formatted HTML.

Comment: now bro whts that...Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in D:\xampplite\htdocs\fetchdata\getdata.php on line 12

Comment: @BhavnishNarang What's your php version? It works in >= 5.3.6

Comment: bro i made a mistake there are multiple table having class name inputpanel fields.i do it with forech loop its wrking..bt now i want them in html format...can you pls help me...thanks bro for ur code..it really helps mre

Comment: @BhavnishNarang `$x->query()` is iterable, so you can put that in a `foreach` and then call `saveHTML()` on each node.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a "Javascript job" with PHP. If your content is XHTML, the best way should be to load the content into DOMDocument and then, search your specific node with XPath, finally retrieve the output of the Element.

check here: http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Note: not sure that will work, but you could try.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to build a function to find and pull it out.

You can use the PHP stristr to check if the table exists. 
The function substr_count will tell you if it exists more than once.

Assuming it is on the page once, let $pagepart = your file_get_contents and $term = "inputpanelfields"

then this should grab the table out of the page

```
$end = mb_stristr($pagepart,$term,false); // Case insensitive; finds the first occurrence
$beg = mb_stristr($pagepart,$term,true); // Case insensitive; finds the first occurrence
$end = mb_stristr($end,'</table>',true); // Case insensitive
$beg = mb_strrichr($beg,'<table',false); // Case insensitive
$beg = str_replace($term,'',$beg);
```

Hope this helps.

Steve

Comment: thnks so much for your early reply...me gona try your code...i think this will solve my pblm.. :)

Comment: hey bro this show only single table records bt i have multiple records with same class name..pls help me in this..i want to fetch all records having class anme inputpanelfields.